# C#: How do I read/write IntPtr to/from memory atomically?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading/writing a global variable in memory like this:

```
var old = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr, ofs);
Marshal.WriteIntPtr(ptr, ofs, nwv);
```

Where ptr is the base pointer in the memory, ofs is the variable offset, old variable receives the current value and nwv is the new value for the global variable. It works well, but I was wondering if there is a way to do it atomically? I know that there is Interlocked.Exchange method, that allows switching IntPtrs, but I can't figure out how to convert ptr+ofs to the ref IntPtr correctly. Will Interlocked.Exchange do IntPtrs switching atomically?

Comment: @Johnny, yes I can, but how do I convert ptr (the actual pointer to memory) to the ref IntPtr, which is required for Interlocked.Echange?

Comment: @Johnny you don't understand. The ptr is the pointer that points to some memory location, when I do ref ptr I get the address of the ptr variable on the stack, and I need the ref to point to memory location.

Comment: @Johnny - Interlocked.Exchange on IntPtrs replaces the contents of an IntPtr *variable*. It doesn't affect the memory currently *pointed at* by that variable (unless it's pointing at itself), which is what your `ptr` identifies as the *target* location. You're missing a level of indirection in how you're thinking about this.

Comment: If it "works well" then what could be the point of doing it atomically?  It can be extremely expensive, depending on the state of the prefetcher and store buffers, it can be ~150x slower.

Answer (score 0):

You need a lock to avoid another C# method to access that location in the middle of your 'atomic' actions. Simplified:

```
static object locker = new object();
lock (locker) {
  //read
  //write
}
```

Only one thread can lock `locker` at at time. Other threads contending for the lock are blocked until the lock is released.

Comment: This global variable is accessed by unmanaged code that I don't control.